# How Keras calculates convolutions 2d in cascaded

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

When I've got more than one Conv2D layer, with only channel, in cascaded in Keras, the final shape corresponds with the (batch, rows, cols, filters) of the last stage. If the number of filters are 1 in all layers, I can calculate the output without any problem, but, whats happens when the number of filters aren't one? For example, in this code I have 3 Conv2D layers with 2,2 and 1 filters. I calculate the result in the second layer:

```
# 1ª etapa
padding = "same"
i_s = (16,32,32) # Batch y tamaño de la imagen de entrada

# 1ª Etapa
f_s_1 = (9,9) # Tamaño del filtro 1
filters_1 = 2 # Número de filtros 1
strides_1 = (1,1) # Strides 1

# 2ª Etapa
f_s_2 = (9,9) # Tamaño del filtro 2 
filters_2 = 2 # Número de filtros 2
strides_2 = (1,1) # Strides 2

# 3ª Etapa
f_s_3 = (9,9) # Tamaño del filtro 2 
filters_3 = 1 # Número de filtros 2
strides_3 = (1,1) # Strides 2

# Matriz de imágenes
I = np.random.random(i_s).astype(np.float32)
If = np.copy(I)
I.shape = (i_s[0],i_s[1],i_s[2],1)

# Convolución 2D mediante keras
model = Sequential()
k_s = (i_s[1],i_s[2],1)
model.add(Conv2D(filters_1, f_s_1, input_shape=k_s, strides=strides_1, padding=padding))
model.add(Conv2D(filters_2, f_s_2, strides=strides_2, padding=padding))
# Calculo la salida en la segunda etapa
reference = model.predict(I)[:,:,:,:] # Convolución de referencia
model.add(Conv2D(filters_3, f_s_3, strides=strides_3, padding=padding))
```

The shape result is *(16,32,32,2)* but I think that the output shape would be *(16,32,32,4)* beacause 2 filters and 2 filters are 4 features... No?

The filters shapes are *(k_h,k_w,filters of the previous layer,filters of the actual layer)*. I neither understand this shape. What is the dimension of *filters of the previous layer*. I catch the filters with this code:

```
# Se coge el filtro de la capa de convolución de keras
filters = model.get_weights()
filters_stg1 = filters[0][:,:,:,:]
filters_stg2 = filters[2][:,:,:,:]
filters_stg3 = filters[4][:,:,:,:]
```

[Shapes of the filters. I don't understand the third dim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG59h.png)

I'm reading about *Convolution over volume*... Is this the process that uses Keras to group the features in only one? What is the math process to group the features?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.

First: The dims in the filters are *(rows, cols, channels, filters)*.

Second: When are 2 or more conv 2d stages in cascaded, Keras uses convolution over volume to calculate for every filter output from the previous stage. This implies the sum of the convolution of every filter output in the previous stage by the filter in the actual layer. In this way it's possible achieve that the output have the same number of filters that the last layer.

The next code implements this feature. The test give an mse error of E-16.

```
# 1ª etapa
padding = "same"
i_s = (16,32,32) # Batch y tamaño de la imagen de entrada

# 1ª Etapa
f_s_1 = (15,15) # Tamaño del filtro 1
filters_1 = 32 # Número de filtros 1
strides_1 = (1,1) # Strides 1
# 2ª Etapa
f_s_2 = (15,10) # Tamaño del filtro 2 
filters_2 = 16 # Número de filtros 2
strides_2 = (1,1) # Strides 2
# 3ª Etapa
f_s_3 = (9,9) # Tamaño del filtro 3
filters_3 = 5 # Número de filtros 3
strides_3 = (1,1) # Strides 3

# Matriz de imágenes
I = np.random.random(i_s).astype(np.float32)
If = np.copy(I)
I.shape = (i_s[0],i_s[1],i_s[2],1)

# Convolución 2D mediante keras
model = Sequential()
k_s = (i_s[1],i_s[2],1)

# Calculo la salida en la primera etapa
model.add(Conv2D(filters_1, f_s_1, input_shape=k_s, strides=strides_1, padding=padding))
# reference_1 = model.predict(I)[:,:,:,:]

# Calculo la salida en la segunda etapa
model.add(Conv2D(filters_2, f_s_2, strides=strides_2, padding=padding))
reference_2 = model.predict(I)[:,:,:,:]

# Calculo la salida en la tercera etapa
model.add(Conv2D(filters_3, f_s_3, strides=strides_3, padding=padding))


# Se coge el filtro de la capa de convolución de keras
filters = model.get_weights()
filters_stg1 = filters[0][:,:,:,:].reshape((np.prod(f_s_1),filters_1))
filters_stg2 = filters[2][:,:,:,:]#.reshape((np.prod(f_s_2),filters_2))
filters_stg3 = filters[4][:,:,:,:]#.reshape((np.prod(f_s_2),filters_2))

# First stage Ouput
If = pad_signal(If, f_s_1, strides_1)
msk, r_shape = conv2d_mask(i_s, f_s_1, strides=strides_1, padding=padding)
result_1 = np.matmul(If.flatten()[msk], filters_stg1).reshape(r_shape+(filters_1,))

acum = 0
stg = np.zeros(r_shape+(filters_2,))
channels = []
msk_2, r_shape = conv2d_mask(i_s, f_s_2, strides=strides_2, padding=padding)
for i in range(filters_2):
    for j in range(filters_1):
        channel = result_1[:,:,:,j]
        filter = filters_stg2[:,:,j,i].reshape((np.prod(f_s_2),1))
        If = pad_signal(channel, f_s_2, strides_2)
        acum += np.matmul(If.flatten()[msk_2], filter).reshape(r_shape)
    stg[:,:,:,i] = acum
    acum = 0

# - reference: Convolución con Keras
# - result   : Convolución con FPGA
# Se comprueba que el resultado es correcto con error medio cuadrático producido
mse = (np.square(reference_2 - stg)).mean(axis=None)
txt = "Test CORRECTO"
if mse > 1e-10:
    txt = "Test INCORRECTO"
print(txt)
```

Comment: Hi Diego, Could you explain your code with a bit more detail. What do pad_signal and conv2d_mask do?